# Fourier transform to decouple pairwise interacting harmonic oscillators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, harmonic-oscillator, many-body, phonons

To solve a Hamiltonian below $$H=\sum_{i}\frac{p^{2}_{i}}{2m_{i}}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j}k_{jj+1}(x_{j}-x_{j+1})^{2} $$ one can do fourier transform to decouple the harmonic oscillators. $$p_{m}=\sum_{q=1}^{N}e^{i2\pi mq}\tilde{p_{q}}$$ $$x_{m}=\sum_{q=1}^{N}e^{i2\pi mq}\tilde{x_{q}}$$ However, is it possible to do the same for pairwise interacting system as below,

$$H=\sum_{i}\frac{p^{2}_{i}}{2m_{i}}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j<l}k_{jl}(x_{j}-x_{l})^{2}$$. is it logically correct to apply such a Fourier transformation ?